# What is the purpose of Django's request._cached_user?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-sessions

New to Django and really trying to build a solid grasp of its built-in authentication and session mechanisms. Looking in the current (v1.8) source code, I see this:

django/contrib/auth/middleware.py

```
def get_user(request):
    if not hasattr(request, '_cached_user'):
        request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
    return request._cached_user

class AuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        assert hasattr(request, 'session'), (
            "The Django authentication middleware requires session middleware "
            "to be installed. Edit your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting to insert "
            "'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' before "
            "'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'."
        )
        request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
```

When I grep through the Django code, I don't see anywhere else that `request._cached_user` is referenced, and nowhere else that this particular `get_user()` is called besides the lambda in the auth middleware. Unless I don't understand middleware, the `process_request()` is only called once per request.

Am I missing an obvious reason why Django is storing `_cached_user` in `request`, never to reference it again?

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I couldn't quite understand the answer below!  It's so odd that there's no reference to `_cached_user` anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of the general Django MVC pattern, Views are passed Requests (not logged in users).

However accessing the authenticated User model is a frequent operation in any Django apps that use login/authentication.

The framework (and in particular the AuthenticationMiddleware) assumes that the authenticated User associated with a Request will not change during the handling of each web request.

For performance reasons, the get_user function retains a reference the associated User and thus avoids repeat database queries for the associated User.

Comment: Any idea how `request._cached_user` differs from `request.user`? Only possibility I can think of is Django trying to mitigate against someone reassigning `request.user` in the View code.

Comment: The presence of the _cached_user attribute won't stop/avoid the 'user' attribute being set during request processing. 

I'm pretty sure it comes down to the use of a SimpleLazyObject which in turn requires that the same object is always returned (in the case copies are made).

Answer (score 1):

Just interpreting Dwight's answer:

I guess `get_user()` function is being called in different places and multiple times in a single request-response cycle. Given `request` being the "global" (not technically global scope) variable gets passed around it makes sense to set the user object as a request attribute.